# vs code source control extremely slow

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, version-control

Not sure what is happening here. Have a .net project I'm working on and I'd rather use vs code however git operations take a really long time. Here's an example:
[image]

As you can see one "git add -A" took over 17 seconds. The file in question is a 6 line settings.json file. Commits, pushes, etc. also take extremely long. Compare this to plain ol' visual studio which is lightning fast compared to this.

Comment: `git add -A` scans the entire working tree, adding every file, not just one file. But this took well under 1 second according to the numbers at the *left*. Are the numbers at the right some sort of measure of CPU time? Perhaps the 17 seconds were *compute* time, spread over 32 processors to take about .5 seconds to scan the entire working tree.

Comment: I don't know what to tell you other than it didn't happen under one second I sat there staring at my source control explorer after hitting the add button. That one small file didn't appear in my staged changes for around 17 seconds.

Comment: The only time I've had Git behave this badly for me was in a VirtualBox VM where I was using their "shared folder" file system to copy files back and forth between the host and the VM. The problem in that particular case was in the VirtualBox shared folder implementation, and I eventually gave up on using it. In any case this is a puzzle, and you might want to use some sort of tracing facility (Git has new internal GIT_TRACE2 stuff for this) to pin it down more precisely.

Comment: @Morks - Did you get anywhere with this? Two weeks ago my VSCode which used to do GIT operations lightning quick is now taking 30s to commit. However, using Sourcetree in the exact same project is quick as it ever was. Something seems to have slowed VSCode down for GIT operations for me recently.

Comment: unfortunately not - just switched to using VS again for now